# Show a message if there are no active posts in category

Tags: wp-query, loop, 404-error

I want to show a specific message or a page or post if there are no active posts in a particular category. Currently, it shows a default "Content not found" message.

I created a new `template-blog.php` file to my child-theme and tried to exchange the 404 part after the

```
<php? else : >
```

tag to no avail. The original part, I think plays a role in that:

```
<?php pinboard_posts_nav(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php pinboard_404(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: What is the URL to this problematic page? `http://example.com/category/some-category/` ? Please be specific while asking questions here

Comment: Hi! Specific page is here https://bhsolutions.eu/category/aktiivsed_konkursid/

Comment: Why dont you change that **Content not found** sentence to your needs??

Comment: Actually, I can't find the place where this text is. It looks like some kind of post-0, but there is no such post under all posts. Also, I want to revel there more information, which I want to be able to format in the post/page edit view.

Comment: Actually, I'm not entirely sure I'm dealing with a pertinent file here. Thus, how I can make sure which file renders the "Content not found" message?